# What is each time through a loop called?

Tags: terminology

```
while ( true )
{
    // what is each time through this loop called?
}
```

Comment: I've flagged this as off-topic merely because I believe this is **better suited** for [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @zzzzBov - I would expect English would close it as off topic.

Comment: @ChrisF, nope, it's a `single-word-request`.

Comment: As someone highly active on ELU, I think that it's better for this forum.

Comment: I think this might well be covered by [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/)

Comment: This question is now [being discussed](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/1994/8) on our meta discussion site.

Answer (score 226):

I would call it an iteration.  I don't know if everyone would.

Comment: Everyone would.

Comment: The definition of "iteration" in the PC-based dictionary I use (WordWeb Pro) is: *"a single execution of a set of instructions that are to be repeated"*, which fits perfectly with "once through this a loop".  So I agree.

Comment: @psr What would it be called to do a single iteration?

Comment: I don't have a nice short way to say that using some form of "iterate".  So even though I would usually prefer that over "loop" or "pass" because of all the patterns and interfaces with some version of "iterate" in the name that make it a more specific technical term, I might just call it a pass, depending on the context.  So maybe librik deserves a little more upvote love.

Comment: There's another answer here: "Pass". Either can be used. These days, iteration seems to be more common.

Comment: iteration baby.

Comment: Yar... iteration... and the i that is often used in for loops is called the **iterator**... and a sweep over all objects in an array is called a **traversal**.

Comment: @quickly_now : "Pass" is commonly used when the code executed differs in each pass. For instance, a two-pass compiler typically has a 'parse' and 'link' pass.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, I know. I also started programming back in the 1980's, and back then "pass" *seemed* to be a more common term. These days, its fallen out of favour, and "iteration" seems to be more prevalent.

Comment: @quickly_now: I disagree, I haven't had your experience with the word pass as a synonym for iteration.

Comment: @jay I would say what you said, a single iteration. That makes it clear it was part of a loop that ended early.

Comment: So if I were to tell a loop to do *an* iteration, would it make sense to tell it to "iterate"? The problem is that "iterate" sounds like looping indefinitely, not just once. If this makes any sense.

Comment: @Jay: Just tell it to "iterate once". Or something like that.

Answer (score 45):

The code inside: body

An execution of the body: iteration

Comment: And code with a body is known as a Code Block.

Answer (score 18):

The usual term is a "pass".  For example: "This code makes ten *passes* through the loop.  On each *pass* it computes a local maximum.  The best result so far was found during the previous *pass* and it will be improved this *pass*."

Comment: I prefer iteration. Pass is something on a large scale, e.g. two passes of the video encoder (which may or may not be in a loop)

Comment: Or worse: A pass might usually include millions of iterations of twenty six different loops

Comment: _Pass_ is also confusing because in some languages it's used specifically to mean _skipping an iteration_.

Answer (score 5):

These days, "iteration" has become the most common general usage.  While "pass" has indeed been used, and is still occasionally seen, it is generally semantically bound more to the transfer of values and references as arguments to method parameters.